# returns blank output for xpath

Tags: php, xpath

i am trying to list all the links and names on the page. i keep getting bank output for the code below

```
$url="http://www.ciim.in/top-pr-dofollow-social-bookmarking-sites-list-2016";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
```

and the nodes part is

```
$nodes = $my_xpath->query( '//table[@class="social_list"]/tbody/tr' );

    foreach( $nodes as $node )
    {

    $title  = $my_xpath->evaluate( 'td[1]/a"]', $node );
    $link  = $my_xpath->evaluate( 'td[1]/a/@href"]', $node );

    echo $title.",".$link."<br>";        

    }
```

note right click on the site is disabled and i use developer tools to inspect the code for the element in chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query

```
$nodes = $xpath->query('//table[@class="social_list"]/tbody/tr/td/a');
```

Inside foreach to get title and URL

```
$title = $node->textContent;
$href = $node->getAttribute('href');
```

Edit:
I've tested this code to retrieve the whole table

```
//Query from parent div
$nodes = $xpath->query('//div[@class="table_in_overflow"]');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $a = $node->getElementsByTagName("a");
    foreach($a as $item) {
      $href =  $item->getAttribute("href");
      $text = $item->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have trailing `"]` at the end of your selectors `'td[1]/a"]'` and `'td[1]/a/@href"]'`, so change these to simply be `td[1]/a` and `td[1]/a/@href`.

Also, you can improve your xpath by selecting only `tr` with a `td` with an `a`, so this will ignore the header which does not have an link.

```
'//table[@class="social_list"]/tbody/tr[td/a]'
```

which will be more efficient than `'//table[@class="social_list"]/tbody/tr'`

Comment: No in your code is an `"]` ad the end. I do not see what this should be. But  do your have only blank output or only for the first row?